# How to use same ID for multiple elements? - ArcText Wordpress Author Name JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using `[ArcText][1]` to render the author names on a curvy path in wordpress. I am a beginner in PHP and JS.

Function:

```
function get_meta($id){
  echo <span id='example1'>".the_author_meta_r("display_name",$id)."</span>
}
```

ArcText Script:

```
var $example1   = $('#example1').hide();

google.load('webfont','1');

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  WebFont.load({
    google        : {
      families    : ['Montserrat','Concert One']
    },
    fontactive    : function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
      init();
    },
    fontinactive  : function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
      init();
    }
  });
});

function init() {
  $example1.show().arctext({radius: 150, dir: -1});         
};
```

To display the author names I use:

```
<?php get_meta(1); ?><?php get_meta(2); ?><?php get_meta(3); ?>
```

Problem is that only (1) renders with curves and other two doesn't because three of them has the same id, and one element can have one id.

Can I rather use class? Since I dont know how many times user will use `<?php get_meta(); ?>`, thats why I am trying to avoid making multiple functions with multiple IDs.

Comment: Use a class. You can only have one ID per element per page.

Comment: Thanks. Just replaced id with class and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_meta($class){
  echo <span id='example1' class='useMultiTimes'>".the_author_meta_r("display_name",$class)."</span>
}
```

Then in the Javascript:

```
var $example1   = $('.useMultiTimes').hide();
```

Or, you can do:

```
var $example1   = $("span[class='useMultiTimes']").hide();
```

But this will possibly hide all the elements with the same class?

```
<?php get_meta('useMultiTimes'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just changed the #example1 with .example1 and worked fine. get_meta($id) was to fetch the author details, it was not being used by JS at all.